# Output only specific items in a txt file according to strings from another list Python

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a list of Strings:

```
myStrings = [Account,Type, myID]
```

I also have a `txt file` with `numbers` associated with these Strings, e.g:

```
[90: 'Account', 5: 'Type', 6: 'MyID', 8: 'TransactionNum', 9: 'Time']
```

How can I print `only the numbers and strings in the txt file` that are `in myStrings`. For example, since `'Time' is not in myStrings`, I `do not want to print it`. I also would like to make this `txt file a list`

Comment: can you show exatly what this txt file contains? its not so clear

Comment: if the text file is created by you, create as json so that its easy to perform the task you required

Comment: if you really want to process as text file, you have to read the content which will be a string, and you need to apply string splits or regex

Comment: the txt file looks like this: 831: 'Account', 30: 'Type'

Comment: do you have `90: 'Account'` , `'5': 'Type'` etc on separate lines in the text-file ?? or you it exactly like what you have showed ?? with `[ ... ]` as single line  ??

Comment: yeah it is all on the single line

Comment: Do u have those sqr brackets at the start? And do u have the text within single quotes? Is the text like ```Account``` or ```'Account'```?

Comment: there are no square brackets, and the text has single quotes

Comment: can you update the question with an example of the txt file?

Comment: I can't figure out how to edit the question, sorry!

Comment: @luchad95 Can u check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
myStrings = ['Account','Type', 'myID']
f = open("D:\\Test.txt","r")
txt = f.read()
f.close()

txt = txt.replace('\n',' ')

txt = txt.split(',')

txtlst = []
for x in txt:
    txtlst.append(x.split(':'))

numslst = [int(txtlst[i][0]) for i in range(len(txtlst))]

strlst = []

for i in txtlst:
    for j in i:
        try:
            int(j)
        except ValueError:
            strlst.append(j.replace("'",""))

for x in range(len(strlst)):
    strlst[x] = strlst[x].replace(' ','')

for x in range(len(strlst)):
    if strlst[x] in myStrings:
        print(numslst[x])
        print(strlst[x])
```

Output:

```
90
Account
5
Type
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have said that the file does not have `[` & `]` , could make it work like so :

```
import json
myStrings = ['Account','Type', 'myID']

with open('text-file.txt') as filename:
  file_text = filename.read()


file_text_list = file_text.split(',')
file_text_dict = {}
for item in file_text_list:
  k, v = item.split()
  v = v.replace("'", "")
  k = k.replace(":", "")
  if v in myStrings:
    file_text_dict[k] = v
print(file_text_dict)  # output => {'90': 'Account', '5': 'Type'}
print(list(file_text_dict.values()))  # output => ['Account', 'Type']
```